# NSScrollview with autohidescrollers notify when scrollbar is hidden

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

Is it possible to get a notification when the scroller gets visible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to putting dynamic amounts of data in a scrollview in which at times it has a scroller and other times it does not.

You can be notified be using this property "hasVerticalScroller."

Once you decide when you want to check this value you can use an NSNotification to broadcast this message.

Comment: I have tried this. I do get KVO on `hasVerticalScroller` firing, but the value of `hasVerticalScroller` always seems to be `true`, so I can't actually determine when it is showing vs hiding. Ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately this plain doesn't work, as the property is always true when the vertical scrollbar has been enabled.

Comment: Seeing as the response it nearly 8 years old and the frequency at which Apple changes their SDK, it most likely has changed.

Comment: If you have a new solution I would recommend posting it as an answer.

Comment: You might need to KVO the hidden property of the NSScroller.